# TestNG is only running first test on each class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, appium

I'm currently working on Intellij with Appium (7.3.0), Java (1.8) and TestNG (6.14.3), it was working fine on Friday and now it is only running the first test on each class like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TevwG.png)

[image]

I have two listeners before and after each method, I've tried debugging and the OnTestSuccess of the first one and it completes normally, and the OnTestStart of the next one does not even start and jumps to the next class.

This only happens when I try to run an XML with more than 1 class, (it runs normally with XML files with one class)

Other thing I have noticed is that when it was working normally, the console showed a list of the tests (that could not be found by regex) and now is not showing.

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Update: Apparently the problem is that the tests now run in different order, they used to run in order

- Class 1

  - Test A (priority 1)
  - Test B (priority 2)
- Class 2

  - Test C (priority 1)
  - Test D (priority 2)

But now they run

- Class 1

  - Test A (priority 1)
- Class 2

  - Test C (priority 1)
- Class 1

  - Test B (priority 2)
- Class 2

  - Test D (priority 2)

How can I make it run like before? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please embed images into the posts where possible, instead of providing links to images.

Comment: what were the code/xml changes since last time it worked? which version of IDEA do you run and were you making any updates of it?

Comment: @HoRn Sure, will do, thanks for the advice

Comment: @quickfix TestNG was updated to 7.6.1 version in pom.xml and it stopped working, the idea version is Intellij and I assume there was a part of the previous version still in cache because the error appeared until the next work day, which made me to not suspect of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a fix, but I managed to solve this behavior on TestNG version 6.9.10 where priority was bugged leading to run one class after the other one